# databaseRef Firebase withoud childByAutoID()

Tags: ios, database, firebase, swift3

Guten Tag,
i'm uploading some text to firebase through my iOS Application, but i can't find a code, where i can give the App User not a random ID, but maybe the email for the id to upload or Name. I hope you understand what i mean.

**Current Code:**

```
let logininit : [String : AnyObject] = ["text4" : text4!, "text5" : text5!, "text6" : text6!]

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Logins").childByAutoId().setValue(logininit)
```

Now i want to remove this childByAutoID, and set it to, how i said, email or name of the user.

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQpd7.png)

**EDIT**

Resolved this Problem: `databaseRef.child("Logins").child(The Email That You Want Here).setValue(logininit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what you meant, but I don't see reasons for you to do that. Usually when you have a new entry on some entity, you usually gives it a unique ID (UUID). So, I think if you use `child(The Email That You Want Here)`, should work as you want:

```
databaseRef.child("Logins").child(The Email That You Want Here).setValue(logininit)
```